# in mvvmcross I'd like to use the same .xib file for two different tableviews (and bindings)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have two table views whose cells are essentially identical in layout composition and style, but their data bindings are different.

I was going to use inheritance to solve this.  The idea is to create a BaseCellView and associate the .xib with that, and then just subclass that BaseCellView, and create the actual bindings in the respective subclass constructors.

Of course that is not working.  I believe the issue is coming from the fact that the tableViewCell customClass is set to BaseCellView -- and so only the BaseCellView ends up getting constructed when the time comes to create the cell.

If I change the customClass in the xib to ACellView, which inherits from BaseCellView, then -- unsurprisingly the ACellView constructor is called and the appropriate bindings happen, but then of course, a second -- and different use of the BaseCellView, perhaps called BCellView, won't work.

So really, the "easy" way out is to just replicate the xib (one for ACellView, and the other of BCellView) and go on my merry way, but that's just kind of crazy.  Any thoughts on how to approach this?

I'd love to be able to override the customClass somehow... though I may well be barking up the wrong tree... thus the post.